# Using variable *name* as property name in object literal

Tags: javascript

Someone just showed me that in a JavaScript object literal, you can use a variable instead of a key-value pair. This results in a property with the variable's name as the key and the variable's value as the value:

```js
var someProperty = "someValue";
var someObject = {
  someProperty
};

//Variable name became property name
alert(someObject.someProperty); //Outputs "someValue"
```

I'd never heard of this syntax before, but we ran it in the Chrome console and it worked. I tested this in the following browsers, and here are the results:

- Chrome 51: works
- Firefox 38: works
- Internet Explorer 11: errors with `Expected ':'`
- Edge 25: works

My questions are

1. Is there a name for this feature?
2. Is this standardised? If so, which standard? ES6?
3. Is there documentation for this somewhere? (Such as on MDN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of ES6, check for shorthand properties http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand